# Creating a circular mask for my graph

Tags: matlab, mask

I'm plotting a square image, but since my camera views out of a circular construction, I want the image to look circular as well. So to do this, I just wanted to create a mask for the image (basically create a matrix, and multiply my data by the mask, so if I want to retain my image I am multiplying by one, and if I want that part of the image to go to black, I multiply by 0).

I'm not sure the best way to make a matrix that will represent a circular opening though. I just want every element within the circle to be a "1" and every element outside the circle to be a "0" so I can color my image accordingly. I was thinking of doing a for loop, but I was hoping there was a faster way to do it. So...all I need is:

- A matrix that is 1280x720
- I need a circle that has a diameter of 720, centered in the middle of the 1280x720 matrix (what I mean by this is all elements corresponding to being within the circle have a "1" and all other elements have a "0"

**My attempt**

```
mask = zeros(1280,720)
for i = 1:1280
    for j = 1:720
        if i + j > 640 && i + j < 1360
            mask(i,j) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Well the above obviously doesn't work, I need to look at it a little better to form a better equation for determing when to add a 1 =P but ideally I would like to not use a for loop

Thanks, let me know if anything is unclear!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@kol 's answer looks correct.  You can do this with vectorized code using the [meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) function.

```
width = 1280;
height = 720;
radius = 360;
centerW = width/2;
centerH = height/2;
[W,H] = meshgrid(1:width,1:height);
mask = ((W-centerW).^2 + (H-centerH).^2) < radius^2;
```

Comment: And the winner is.....PeterM! This worked perfectly except  for the radius should be 360 instead of 720. This code took 0.0271 seconds while kol's, while correct as well, takes 0.0763 seconds. So almost 3 times faster to do it this way, thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://ideone.com/HdHz5r) is a possible solution:

```
width = 160;
height = 120;
mask = zeros(width, height);

center_x = width / 2;
center_y = height / 2;
radius = min(width, height) / 2;
radius2 = radius ^ 2;
for i = 1 : width
  for j = 1 : height
    dx = i - center_x;
    dy = j - center_y;
    dx2 = dx ^ 2;
    dy2 = dy ^ 2;
    mask(i, j) = dx2 + dy2 <= radius2;
  end;
end;

picture = randn(width, height); % test image :)
masked_image = picture .* mask;
imagesc(masked_image);
```

Comment: Thanks this works! I'm interested to see others have faster solutions, but + 1 for now =)